# Cpanel revert/restore site in public_html folder

Tags: cpanel

Cpanel has live site, yesterday i just copy and paste a zip copy of themeforest template and extract to public_html folder the problem is that after I extracted it the live site changed.

I didn't have a back up since am new to cpanel file manager is there anyway i can revert or return the original site?please i need your help, my friend told me i cannot ask the cpanel technical support since i dont have authorization. Can anyone solved this issue and happen to you?what did you do to solve this?

Comment: how do i know the changes and existing files that has been present in public_html folder?and extracted files in it?

Comment: have you check the trash folder?